# Plotting vertical profile of wind barbs with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot the two horizontal wind components u and v in a vertical profile using matplotlib. Next to that, I would like to plot wind barbs at the same heights, so that the two plots share the y-axis. I would like to use the sharey-option so that i can control the ylimits more easily using values of z.

So far I did this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

u = np.array([1,2,3,5,7,7,7,7])
v = np.array([-1,-1,-1,1,3,3,3,3])
z = np.array([2,10,50,100,200,300,400,500])

fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=[15,8],ncols=2,sharey=True)
ax[0].plot(u,z,label='U-component')
ax[0].plot(v,z,label='V-component')
ax[0].axvline(0,color='k')
ax[0].legend(loc=4)

Xq,Yq = np.meshgrid(1,np.arange(0,u.shape[0]))
ax[1].barbs(Xq,Yq,u,v)

plt.show()
```

which gives me the following plot:

[image with sharey-option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lI72Z.png)

As you can see, the barb-function plots the wind barbs against the index of the array, but i would like to plot it against my z-array (just like I did with the u and v arrays). It should look something like this:

[without sharey-option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WR6nu.png)

Here I simply switched off the sharey-option to show what I would like to have. But as I mentioned, with this option I cannot set the ylimits of the barb-plot using z-values.

Can anyone help me to get this done?

I hope I made myself clear, if not, please help me to improve my question. The code should work as a minimal working example.

thanks in advance

philipp

Comment: This doesn't make any sense -> *with this option I cannot set the ylimits of the barb-plot using z-values.*

Comment: OK, so how can I control the ylimits of the barb-blot using values from my z-array?

Just to clarify, I meant if I use sharey=False, I have to set the ylimits independently, and then there is still the issue that the index is plotted in the vertical axis and not the height.

I'm not sure if I'm mistaken, so maby you could explain where I'm wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I understood correctly, but if I did then you should try changing the meshgrid line to:

```
Xq,Yq = np.meshgrid(1, z)
```

The point being setting the barbs origin to be at (1, z) coordinate.

Comment: Of course. That was my error in reasoning.

Thank you very much !!